# Getting [object Promise] when outputting result of promise

Tags: node.js, promise, amazon-sqs

I am getting `Result is: [object Promise]` when I am calling this promise. I want to be able to work with the data that comes out of it. I am expecting the result to be an array of messages from my SQS queue.

I currently have more than 10 messages in the queue so should be fine finding some.

This is my code currently:

```
let params = {
        QueueUrl: config.aws.serviceQueue,
        VisibilityTimeout: 60, 
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 10
    };

  let getMonitors = sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise();

  let result = getMonitors.then(function(data) {
    console.log('Success');
    return data;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
console.log(`Result is: ${result}`);
```

What am I missing here? I am very new to promises so please bear with me if I don't understand your answer or question.

Comment: Where is the console log for `Result is [object Promise]`? Presumably you are logging the Promise and not the result...

Comment: @James That is the console.log output

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the result of `getMonitors().then()` is a promise object so the `result` variable is indeed a promise object.  That's how promises work.

If you want to access the value inside the promise, you either use `.then()` on the promise or you use `await` (inside an `async` tagged function).

In this particular code, you should just be consuming the result inside your `.then()` handler.  That's where you have the value.

Comment: There's no way of assigning the results of that promise to a variable that I can access in other parts of my file?

Comment: @JoshKirby - Welcome to asynchronous programming.  No, you can't just treat an asynchronous operation as synchronous in Javascript.  They don't work that way.  You can get some synchronous feel to the code by using `async` and `await` instead of `.then()`.  There are thousands of articles on how `async` and `await` work so I won't attempt to repeat all that here.

Comment: @JoshKirby return the promise from the function, and in the consumer, chain a `.then()` to get the result.

Comment: @jfriend00 From what I know of async/await I need to know promises well so that is out.

Comment: @JoshKirby - `async/await` is one additional tool to use with promises.  You do need to understand promises in general, but there's no reason not to learn the extra tools you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You return something in then and try to assign it to any variable you will end up with having promise.

What you can do is

```
let params = {
   QueueUrl: config.aws.serviceQueue,
   VisibilityTimeout: 60,
   MaxNumberOfMessages: 10
};`

let getMonitors = sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise();

/*let result = getMonitors.then(function(data) {
     console.log('Success');
     return data;
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });*/
//console.log(``Result is: ${result}``);`

getMonitors.then(function (result) {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

or you can use Async and await ::

```
const someFunction = Async() => {
   /* your all code inside*/
   let result = await getMonitors();
   console.log(Result is: $ {
      result
   });
   or
   console.log(Result is: $ {
      await result
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to look at the data before the promise has resolved. Async/ await will probably help.

```
async function happyLittleFunc() {
  const params = {
    QueueUrl: config.aws.serviceQueue,
    VisibilityTimeout: 60,
    MaxNumberOfMessages: 10
  };

  let getMonitors;

  try {
    getMonitors = await sqsReceieveMessage(params);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(`Result is: ${getMonitors}`);
}

// Call sqs
function sqsReceieveMessage(params) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let messageData;

    try {
      messageData = await sqs.receiveMessage(params);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    resolve(messageData);
  });
}

happyLittleFunc();
```